# How do I use SortField to sort my data numerically in Flex/ActionScript?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, sorting

From the documentation:

**SortField () constructor**

```
public function SortField(name:String = null, caseInsensitive:Boolean = false, descending:Boolean = false, numeric:Object = null)
```

I'm confused on the last part - `numeric:Object = null`.

Here is my function:

```
private function createXMLDataProvider():XMLListCollection{
    var sort:Sort = new Sort();
    sort.fields = [new SortField("@sortorder",true,false,true), new SortField("@label")];
    var searchTypesCollection:XMLListCollection = 
        new XMLListCollection(getAssociations(_appData.searchTypes, "category", searchType));
    searchTypesCollection.sort = sort;
    searchTypesCollection.refresh();
    return searchTypesCollection;
}
```

On this line:

```
sort.fields = [new SortField("@sortorder",true,false,true), new SortField("@label")];
```

The first SortField is a number but is being compared like it is text. What should I be putting where it says true?

Also from the documentation:

Specifies that if the field being sorted contains numeric (number/int/uint) values, or string representations of numeric values, the comparator use a numeric comparison. If this property is false, fields with string representations of numbers are sorted using strings comparison, so 100 precedes 99, because "1" is a lower string value than "9". If this property is null, the first data item is introspected to see if it is a number or string and the sort proceeds based on that introspection.

The default value is false.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here for an example of sorting an XMLListCollection:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-the-sortfield-and-sort-classes/

If you scroll down to Vivek's comment, there's an example and a follow-up comment from Peter deHaan.  It looks like he's just omitting the caseInsensitive property, rather than setting it explicitly in the constructor, e.g.:

```
var sortField:SortField = new SortField(value);
sortField.numeric = true;
sortField.descending = true;

var sort:Sort = new Sort();
sort.fields = [sortField];
xmlListColl.sort = sort;
return xmlListColl.refresh();
```

Hope that helps! Incidentally, true is correct for the numeric property -- I'm not sure why it accepts Object; it looks like in Flex 2, it was a Boolean, and in Gumbo, it's still an Object, although the following line's been added to the Gumbo docs:

> When this property is modified, it
>   dispatches the numericChanged event.

A clue, perhaps?  Nevertheless, a Boolean value is fine, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but `caseInsensitive` and `numeric` fields seem like an either-or choice to me, that is, if you set `caseInsensitive` to `true`, there is no real point in also setting `numeric`, and vice versa. Try modifying the above line as follows and see if it works that way.

```
sort.fields = [new SortField("@sortorder",false,false,true), new SortField("@label")];
```